# Storing changes/versions of a table row in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I'm wanting to be able to see and also query with PHP changes to rows of a table so I can see the history.

For example if someone changes a title for a product name, I can see the different versions and when they were changed.

What's the best way to go about this, does MySQL have a particular feature to handle this or is it a case of creating a table for historic changes with fields for date changed then before and after of a particular field?

Comment: Create a log table where you add a new entry each time anyone adds/updates/inserts something to the database with info who it was and what they changed. That's probably the easiest way to do it if you want to be able to easily view or query the log for specific actions.

Comment: You are looking for a feature called “audit trail”. That’s not built in in MySQL but you can build it yourself using triggers as @MagnusEriksson is suggesting you

Comment: Thanks @MagnusEriksson - it is possible this table could get large based on the amount of field changes I'd want to log, currently there are over 1million records doing it in a similar way. Would you advise splitting it into multiple tables depending on the group of fields being changed (e.g. a table for stock and price changes, then a table for title and description changes) or just keep it a single table?

Comment: If you have multiple tables, it will probably be easier to maintain and use (just my opinion). Then you can also create real foreign key relationships that references the rows that were modified. Then it can also use proper indexes which will help when searching the logs. That's harder for generic columns that could contain anything. It will also allow you to have different columns in your logs for different table entities if needed. So basically, you can have one log per table, where it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a data warehousing There are generally 2 Methods:

1. create a slow moving Dimension
2. create an Audit Table as suggested above

## 1) Slow Moving or Slow Changing Dimension

These are great for tracking a number of changes at a given time - 1 or more values may change at the same time - this stores all the changes and unchanged data in a new row - identified by a timestamp.

No so good at knowing what specific data has changed.
Good at showing a current position of the Stock etc.

For Example, If your product table currently consisted of:

```
PRODUCT_ID
PRODUCT_NAME
PRODUCT_COST
```

you would add additional fields to track changes, for example

```
VALID_FROM
VALID_TO
```

**When a Product is added** the VALID_FROM will be the datetime it is added and the VALID_TO a date such as 31DEC3000... Note this record is always valid until it is changed.

**When a PRODUCT is updated:**
Change the old product record that had a VALID_TO of 31DEC3000 to the current DATETIME
and
add a new record with VALID_FROM being the current datetime... VALID_TO would be the future datetime you have decided on.

Anytime you query your data you need to know when you want the data to be 'As Of' so you can query with something like :

```
where AS_OF_DATETIME is between (VALID_FROM and VALID_TO)
```

## 2) Audit Table Method

An Audit table stores individual variable changes and would usually consist of a standard set of columns.

This is great at knowing what specific data has changed.
Not so good at showing a current position of the Stock etc.

```
TABLE    /* Table the Changes were made */
ID       /* ID or key to the data in the table */
VARIABLE /* The name of the variable that changed */
DATETIME /* Date and Time of the Change */
BEFORE   /* The Value of the variable before the Change */
AFTER    /* The Value of the Variable after the change */
USER     /* Who made the change */
PROCESS  /* By what process the change was made */
```